# Cannot POST on JS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, post

I'm very new to web development, and now I'm trying to build a login page which uses HTML, CSS and Javascript for the website, and MongoDB database to store the data received from the user. I followed a few tutorials on YouTube, but for some reasons the data cannot be posted.

Here are the codes that I have so far:

(Javascript)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( {extended: true}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://cs196:cs196@userdata.sn7wv.mongodb.net/cs196", { userNewUrlParser: true}, {useUnifiedTopology: true} );

// create a data schema

const notesSchemaCreate = {
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    confirm_password: String
}

const Note = mongoose.model("NoteCreate", notesSchemaCreate)

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    let newNote = new Note({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirm_password: req.body.confirm_password
    });
    newNote.save();
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("server is running on 3000")
})
```

(And here are the HTML codes)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Create an account -->
        <form class="form form--hidden" id="createAccount" method= "post" action="/">

            <h1 class="form__title">Create Account</h1>
            <div class="form__message form__message--error"></div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input type="text" id="signupUsername" class="form__input" name="username" autofocus placeholder="Username">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form__input" name= "email" autofocus placeholder="Email Address">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input type="password" class="form__input" name= "password" autofocus placeholder="Password">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input type="password" class="form__input" name= "confirm_password" autofocus placeholder="Confirm Password">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <button class="form__button" type="submit">Continue</button>
            <p class="form__text">
                <a class="form__link" href="./" id="linkLogin">Already have an account? Sign In</a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm trying out the results using `localhost:3000`, which looks like this:
[image]

The result simply gave me `cannot POST /`  in a new page.

Please let me know if there might be something off with my MongoDB setting, or if you want to see how the setting is right now, since I don't know what parts to show you guys and I don't want to make this post incredibly long.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me out with this! And I apologize in advance if my codes or this post is formatted horribly.

Comment: Aside from you missing `res.end()` after `newNote.save();` line it seems to work. Go ahead and add `res.end()` in your `post` method as it gets stuck until eventually it times out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each endpoint function must end the request-response cycle by sending a response ( `res.send(), res.json(), res.end()`, etc).
2. `model.create()` is asyncronous. Mark your function as `async`

So the solution would be:

```
app.post("/", async(req, res) => {
    try {
      const newUser = await Note.create({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirm_password: req.body.confirm_password
      });

      res.json({status: "success", message: "user created successfully", user: newUser})

    } catch(error) {
        res.json({status: "fail", message: error.message ? error.message : "could not create user"})
    }
    
})
```

P.S: never expose your secret(mongo_uri, stripe_key, etc.) keys public.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. However, now instead of pushing data into MongoDB, it just keeps loading after I press "continue". Any idea on what causes this problem?

Comment: @BryantHsiung Make sure that your request is hitting the correct endpoint: `app.post("/", function(req, res) { console.log("request has hit with post method"); let newNote = new Note(.........` if everything is correct you will see the message in youe nodejs console. (not browser console)

Comment: Ok just a quick update. I got a few of ```"UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection"```, ```"DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated."``` (the actual message is a big long and it won't fit into this comment section, but I think basically are the repeats of the above errors).

Comment: @BryantHsiung "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection", "DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated." means you don't have global error handler in your express app. You should set up a global error handler to catch any errors. Otherwise you must use `try/catch` for asyncronous tasks